# Have there been any murderers in America who would have been put to death under the following (proposed) "three strikes" rule?

Tags: united-states, capital-punishment

Let's say that society is technically in favor of capital punishment, but fears executing innocent people. So it adopts a "three strikes" rule that says that capital punishment can be inflicted only on people that have been convicted of murder in at least three separate trials by three separate juries for three separate acts of murder (not three deaths from one single act). To take one example, [Ted Kaczynski, the Unbomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Kaczynski) was convicted of multiple murders. But I believe it was at one trial by one jury, which would not "qualify" (if my understanding is correct).

Was there ever at leastanyone living in America at the time of their death, whose execution would have taken place under such a "three strikes" rule.

Comment: Generally, charges are grouped together into one trial (and one trial = one jury, unless there is a mistrial in which case the prior trial is considered "thrown out"), unless multiple sovereigns are involved. It is possible if the murders occur across state lines, or clearly separated (e.g. after incarceration), or specially protected persons (e.g. government officers in duty, witnesses or jurors). "Redoing" valid trials is not really a thing in US law...Do all of the strikes have to be murder?

Comment: @sharur: The way I constructed the question, yes. The issue is not three "murders" but three "convictions" in three different trials by three different juries for three different acts. So e.g. "Ted Kaczynski" would have to be convicted of e.g. a bombing attack, a machine gun attack, and a fatal stabbing, to be put to death.

Comment: Yes, although this is just borderline a law question as opposed to a general true crime history question. Quite a few serial killers and gang hitmen have fit this description.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Do they, really, if they don't cross state lines? I would imagine most murder charges would be grouped into one trial, would they not?

Comment: @Libra: I know California has a "three-strikes" law, that mandates a life sentence for three "serious felony" convictions. Presumably some of the individuals sentenced under that would qualify if California were to implement your theoretical law (California does have the death penalty on the books, and can sentence people to death, but has a moratorium on actually carrying out those sentences)

Comment: @sharur No. typically they are only grouped in one trial if there is a common nucleus of facts and circumstances. Common in mass shootings, and not in serial killings at different places and different times (which also do often cross state lines).